# Counting process with independent, stationary increments is Poisson

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Suppose that $L_t$ is a counting process, i.e.
$$
L_t= \sum_{i \in \mathbb N} 1_{T_i \le t}
$$
for a collection $(T_i) _{i \in \mathbb N}$ of stopping times.

I have often seen the claim that if $L_t$ has stationary and independent increments, then it is Poisson, that is there exists $\lambda>0$ s.t.
$$
\mathbb P(L_t=k) =e^{- \lambda t} \frac{(\lambda t) ^k }{k!} 
$$

Is this claim correct or is it missing some assumptions? Could someone prove this fact or point to a reference for a proof?

Comment: Not an answer, but you may be interested in reading about [Lévy processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy_process).

Comment: Take a look at Theorem 8.1 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.00251)